# Convert Dictionary object to another Dictionay object rxjs Angular typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I have the below dictionary which has the return type as `{ [key: string]: QueryBuilderFieldsDto }`

```
{
    "2221": {
        "label": "Risk Domain",
        "name": "2221",
        "type": "dropdown",
        "typeLabel": "Dropdown",
        "isStandardField": false,
        "fieldEntityType": 2,
        "fieldEntityTypeLabel": "Risk",
        "options": [{
            "uniqueId": null,
            "id": 2636,
            "name": "Unassigned",
            "isOrganizationUnit": false
        }]
    },
    "2222": {
        "label": "Number Field",
        "name": "2222",
        "type": "number",
        "typeLabel": "Number",
        "isStandardField": false,
        "fieldEntityType": 2,
        "fieldEntityTypeLabel": "Risk"
    }
}
```

Properties of `QueryBuilderFieldsDto` describe below

```
export interface QueryBuilderFieldsDto {
    name: string;
    label: string;
    value?: string;
    type: string;
    nullable?: boolean;
    options?: Option[] | FieldOptionsDto[];
    operators?: string[];
    defaultValue?: any;
    defaultOperator?: any;
    isStandardField: boolean;
    fieldEntityType: number;
    fieldEntityTypeLabel?: string;
    typeLabel?: string;
    validator?: (rule: Rule, parent: RuleSet) => any | null;
}
```

Now I want to add an extra property over the dictionary object

```
   validator: (rule) => {
     if (rule.value == undefined || rule.value == "") {
       return {
         age: {
           rule: rule,
           message: 'Value cannot be empty'
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Example

```
"2222": {
            "label": "Number Field",
            "name": "2222",
            "type": "number",
            "typeLabel": "Number",
            "isStandardField": false,
            "fieldEntityType": 2,
            "fieldEntityTypeLabel": "Risk",
            validator: (rule) => {
            if (rule.value == undefined || rule.value == "") {
             return {
             age: {
               rule: rule,
               message: 'Value cannot be empty'
               }
             }
           }
         }
       }
    }
```

I am subscribing to the Observable

```
this.metricCreateConfigureStore.queryBuilderFields$.subscribe(item => {
      this.fields = item as { [key: string]: QueryBuilderFieldsDto };
    })
```

This returns the value without `validator` property, I know we use `pipe` and `map` to return the desired value, but not sure how to do it, the return type from the map should be

```
{ [key: string]: QueryBuilderFieldsDto }
```

The return type of `queryBuilderFields` is `queryBuilderFields$: Observable<{ [key: string]: QueryBuilderFieldsDto; }>`

Tried something like below but got an error on vscode

[image]

Comment: It seems to work as expected, maybe I misunderstood something? https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-z1sqwe?file=index.ts

Comment: @HarisBouchlis I need to map validator: (rule) => {} on data, The data doesn't contain validator property. On your case you are already hard coded validator. That doesn't exists at the beginning. It suppose to be added later

Comment: Got you, but even if you do it with pipe/map the original data will not be changed, just the value you get in the subscription where you do the pipe/map. Is that what you need?

Comment: @HarisBouchlis we can use the map function to return the new value that contains validator. Update the question with new image for new value

Answer (score 1):

The question is basically how to `map` a key/value pair in rxjs. As far as I know `map` cannot do that, instead I would use `reduce`. This is how I would go about it:

```
from(Object.entries(data)) // convert object to [key, value]
  .pipe(
    reduce((obj, item) => {
      item[1].validator = validatorFn; // add the validator function to the value
      obj[item[0]] = item[1]; // convert [key, value] back to object
      return obj;
    }, {})
  )
  .subscribe((result) => {
    console.log(result);
  });
```

[working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-z1sqwe?file=index.ts)

**EDIT**: If you are expecting an asynchronous stream of data you can replace reduce with scan ([docs](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/scan))

Answer (score 0):

The error you see in vscode has following reason:

Map functions can be defined in full or short

`map(foo => bar)`

`map(foo => { return bar; })`

In your screenshot the curly brackets belong to the 2nd variant, which means to the map function. They do NOT belong to the object you try to return.

Either add () around {}

`map(foo => ({ bar: 'baz'}))`

Or add the return statement

`map(foo => { return { bar: 'baz' } })`

Comment: How do I return the dictionary with key-value pair

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
    this.metricCreateConfigureStore.queryBuilderFields$
      .map((data) => {
        var mapValue: { [key: string]: Field; } = {};
        Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
          mapValue[key] = this.mapField(data[key]);
        });
        return mapValue;
      })
      .subscribe(item => {
        this.fields = item as { [key: string]: Field };
      })
  }




private mapField(field: QueryBuilderFieldsDto): Field {
    const fields =
      {
        name: field.name,
        label: field.label,
        type: field.type,
        typeLabel: field.typeLabel,
        options: field.options,
        isStandardField: field.isStandardField,
        fieldEntityTypeLabel: field.fieldEntityTypeLabel,
        fieldEntityType: field.fieldEntityType,
        validator: (rule) => {
          if (rule.value == undefined || rule.value == "") {
            return {
              'required': {
                rule: rule,
                message: 'Value cannot be empty'
              }
            }
          }
        }
      } as Field;
    return fields;
  }
```